# Fit a div with a background image inside another styled div

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.dl {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: pink;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px red solid
}
```

```html
<div class="dl">
  <div style="background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/04/Sprite_Remix_3_Versions.jpg); width:160px; height:323px; margin:0 auto">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to fit a div with a background image inside a div container. Right now, the inner div's width and height of its background image are larger than the container.

How would I go about doing this?  Below is a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: add to the div : "max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; background-size: 100% auto;"

Comment: @ Mr. Alien Will You Look into this @Mr. Alien

Answer (score 6):

I have changed inline style to external if you want to change the image you can change `background-position-x` it will work as it is a sprite image

```css
.dl {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px red solid;
  display:inline-block;
}
.dl div {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/04/Sprite_Remix_3_Versions.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.dl:nth-of-type(2) div{
  background-position-x: 50%;
}
.dl:nth-of-type(3) div{
  background-position-x: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dl">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dl">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dl">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: means i am confused? @DineshKanivu

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/spidiweb/dhgnampc/1/) is your desired output.

You have added a different width to the background image. The best thing can be done is set the width and height of the inner div to 100%.
**HTML**

```
<div class="dl">
    <div class='d2' style="background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/04/Sprite_Remix_3_Versions.jpg); margin:0 auto"> </div>
</div>
```

**And CSS**

```
.dl{width:200px; height:200px; background:pink; text-align:center; border:1px red solid}
.d2{height:100%;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use background-size property..

Here is the result of it..

https://jsfiddle.net/dhgnampc/16/

html:

```
<div class="dl">

<div style="background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/04/Sprite_Remix_3_Versions.jpg)no-repeat 0 0;
        margin:30px auto;
      background-size:contain;">
 </div>
```

css:

```
 .dl{width:200px; height:200px; background:pink; 
    text-align:center; border:1px red solid}

 .dl div{width:100%;height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css code

```
.dl > div {

height: 100%;

}
```

and remove inline style height and width.